# How to setup a marker or a background color to a particular line in the editor given its line number?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

> Hi, I m doing a eclipse plugin project to create an IDE like eclipse
>   for a particular language.
>
> when the program written in my IDE is having errors,it throws the
>   errors to the console view which i have created in my IDE.but when the
>   user clicks on a particular,i should highlight or set a marker for the
>   line having the error.
>
> I know the line number having the error.How shall i set the background
>   color or a marker to indicate the user that this line is having the
>   selected error?
>
> How shall i do this in java?
>
> Can anyone help me in doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `MarkerUtilities.createMarker(IResource, Map, String)` with something like this:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

map.put(IMarker.MESSAGE, "My message");
map.put(IMarker.LINE_NUMBER, Integer.valueOf(myLine));
map.put(IMarker.CHAR_START, Integer.valueOf(myStartRegion));
map.put(IMarker.CHAR_END, Integer.valueOf(myEndRegion));
map.put(IMarker.SEVERITY, Integer.valueOf(IMarker.SEVERITY_INFO));
map.put(IMarker.PRIORITY, Integer.valueOf(IMarker.PRIORITY_NORMAL));

org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.MarkerUtilities.createMarker(myFile, map, MARKER_ID);
```

With your `MARKER_ID` matching the description of a "markerType" in your plugin.xml

See the extension points

- `org.eclipse.ui.editors.annotationTypes`
- `org.eclipse.ui.editors.markerAnnotationSpecification`
- `org.eclipse.core.resources.markers`

You can find an example for the error marker in [**this plugin.xml**](https://github.com/eclipse/acceleo/blob/master/plugins/org.eclipse.acceleo.ide.ui/plugin.xml). Look for references to marker. The design of the marker is defined in plugin.xml